# Cross Compiling for ARM Cortex-A57 MPcore

Tags: c, arm, cross-compiling

I have to cross compile my C/C++ libraries for ARM Cortex-A57 MPcore. Previously I did cross compiling using `arm-linux-gnueabihf` but this time I don't know how should i proceed. Which `toolchain` should I use? Any guidance will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Who is the vendor? E.g. Freescale distributes Yocto that gives you bsp, examples and complete toolchains. As far as I know Atmel also use Yocto to support their mid/high level CPUs.

Comment: Qualcom is the vendor. Their Snapdragon series.

Comment: In GCC-land, at least, the relevant triplets are `aarch64-<something>-<something>-`; beyond that, whether you "should" target Linux, bare-metal, or something else, and _whose_ customised flavour of toolchain you "should" choose, strays into opinion territory.

Comment: If you just want to experiment, ELLCC can target arm-eabihf and aarch64. There are binary downloads of the tool chain that run on Linux, Mac OS X, and Windows. http://ellcc.org